# error from inside the android tools, check the console in processing 3.3.5 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, processing

i am new to processing and wanted to make apps using processing,
but i am not able to run a basic code in the android mode in ubuntu

i tried finding the solution to this, but i could only find it for windows,

i have installed java version 1.8

please help, it will be really appreciated

the error i am encountering is,

```
1. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/MainActivity.java (at line 11)
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat is never used
----------
2. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/MainActivity.java (at line 15)
    import android.Manifest;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import android.Manifest is never used
----------
3. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/MainActivity.java (at line 49)
    int check;
        ^^^^^
The value of the local variable check is not used
----------
----------
4. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/sa.java (at line 4)
    import processing.data.*; 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import processing.data is never used
----------
5. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/sa.java (at line 5)
    import processing.event.*; 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import processing.event is never used
----------
6. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/sa.java (at line 6)
    import processing.opengl.*; 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import processing.opengl is never used
----------
7. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/sa.java (at line 8)
    import java.util.HashMap; 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import java.util.HashMap is never used
----------
8. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/sa.java (at line 9)
    import java.util.ArrayList; 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import java.util.ArrayList is never used
----------
9. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/sa.java (at line 10)
    import java.io.File; 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import java.io.File is never used
----------
10. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/sa.java (at line 11)
    import java.io.BufferedReader; 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import java.io.BufferedReader is never used
----------
11. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/sa.java (at line 12)
    import java.io.PrintWriter; 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import java.io.PrintWriter is never used
----------
12. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/sa.java (at line 13)
    import java.io.InputStream; 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import java.io.InputStream is never used
----------
13. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/sa.java (at line 14)
    import java.io.OutputStream; 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import java.io.OutputStream is never used
----------
14. WARNING in /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/src/processing/test/sa/sa.java (at line 15)
    import java.io.IOException; 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import java.io.IOException is never used
----------
14 problems (14 warnings)

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
input: /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/classes
input: /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/libs/android-support-v4.jar
input: /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/libs/processing-core.jar
Pre-Dexing /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/libs/android-support-v4.jar -> android-support-v4-4a45b30e6f029e45cd804738867ce484.jar
Pre-Dexing /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/libs/processing-core.jar -> processing-core-e5aa8bee33bb8c16a67b91c03a0cc33a.jar
Converting compiled files and external libraries into /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex #1 (9 defs/5.7KiB)
       [dx] Merged dex #2 (1153 defs/1127.0KiB)
       [dx] Merged dex #3 (171 defs/703.5KiB)
       [dx] Result is 1333 defs/2250.4KiB. Took 0.6s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png => /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png: 52% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png => /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png => /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png: 74% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/res/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png => /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png: 89% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/icon.png => /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/icon.png: 89% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/res/drawable/icon.png => /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /tmp/android5161046717281048963sketch/bin/res/drawable/icon.png: 84% size of source)
   [crunch] Crunched 6 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
Creating full resource package...

-package:
Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
Creating sa-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

BUILD FAILED
/home/satinder/sketchbook/modes/AndroidMode/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:958: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/satinder/sketchbook/modes/AndroidMode/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:969: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/satinder/sketchbook/modes/AndroidMode/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:312: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Failed to create key: Cannot run program "/home/satinder/Downloads/processing-3.3.5/java/bin/keytool": error=2, No such file or directory
JAVA_HOME is set to: /home/satinder/Downloads/processing-3.3.5/java
Update it if necessary, or manually execute the following command:
/home/satinder/Downloads/processing-3.3.5/java/bin/keytool -genkey -alias AndroidDebugKey -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US" -validity 10950 -keypass android -keystore /home/satinder/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.getDebugKey(ApkBuilder.java:300)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:392)
    at com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask.execute(ApkBuilderTask.java:334)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidBuild.antBuild(AndroidBuild.java:525)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidBuild.build(AndroidBuild.java:96)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidMode.handleRunEmulator(AndroidMode.java:259)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidEditor$15.run(AndroidEditor.java:511)

Total time: 23 seconds
```

Comment: What was the solution for Windows?

Comment: sir i have not verified this but it is said that go to C:\Users\<UserName>\.android\debug.keystore   and delete debug.keystore

Comment: Can you find the `debug.keystore` file on your system and delete it?

Comment: sir earlier i tried on ubuntu but when u mentioned about windows, i tried in windows too and i was able to delete the debug.keystore but unfortunately it didn't work out

Comment: Does the `/home/satinder/Downloads/processing-3.3.5/java/bin/keytool` file exist?

Comment: sir if u are asking in the folder from which i installed processing then "NO", there was no such file, the files there are controlPanel,java,jcontrol,jjs,pack200 and unpack200

Comment: Then there's a hint. The error is saying it can't find that file. Now you just need to find out why that file isn't present on your system. Did you maybe miss an installation step?

Comment: but sir when i open processing and start the android mode, then it asks for installing SDK manually or automatically, i always chose automatically and it downloads the sdk then why is the problem there

Comment: and the file i have downloaded is form the official processing website

Comment: and sir i would also like to thank you for taking out your precious time and answering my question

Comment: I don'y know why it isn't there, maybe the automatic download hits an error or something. Have you tried doing the manual installation?

Comment: no sir i have not tried it yet , but i will try doing that

Comment: sir i don't know how but when i reinstalled processing in open cv and then for the manual installation i install android studio i was able to make apps in processing